# Pandas flatten a file

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data :

```
A, B, c1 , c2, c3
01001,First cat,0,0,0
01001,Second Cat,0,0,0
01002,First cat,183,0,0
01002,Second cat,183,0,6
```

Which I would like to be:

```
A, B, col, First cat, Second Cat
01001,c1, 0,0,0
01001,c2, 0,0,0
01001,c3, 0,0,0
01002,c1, 183,183,0
01002,c2, 0,0,0
01002,c3, 0,0,6
```

So I guess it is called unflatten a file?
My idea was to read each line and reparse manually the entire file. I am wondering if there is a quickway in pandas or similar.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.melt(['A','B']).pivot(['A','variable'], 'B','value').fillna(0).reset_index()
print (df)
B      A variable First cat Second Cat Second cat
0  01001       c1         0          0          0
1  01001       c2         0          0          0
2  01001       c3         0          0          0
3  01002       c1       183          0        183
4  01002       c2         0          0          0
5  01002       c3         0          0          6
```

Or [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['A','B']).stack().unstack(level=1, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
B      A level_1 First cat Second Cat Second cat
0  01001      c1         0          0          0
1  01001      c2         0          0          0
2  01001      c3         0          0          0
3  01002      c1       183          0        183
4  01002      c2         0          0          0
5  01002      c3         0          0          6
```

Comment: Second option works for me, not the first, thank you for your help !

Comment: Regarding, first solution, this correction works : `df = pd.pivot_table(df.melt(['A','B']),index=['A','variable'],columns='B',values='value').fillna(0).reset_index()`

Comment: @Pdeuxa - Maybe you need upgrade pandas ;)

Comment: @Pdeuxa: First solution works for me, pandas version 1.1.4.

Comment: Indeed, I was 1.0.5, a 'bit old. Thanks !